# mosquitto_pub config file format

Tags: mosquitto

Some MQTT-brokers accept auth-tokens as username (e.g. mqtt.flespi.io). In `man mosquitto_pub` I found that clients support configuration files:

> **FILES**
>
> $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mosquitto_sub, $HOME/.config/mosquitto_pub
>     Configuration file for default options.

But there are no clarification about file format. I tried this:

```
username=foobar..token
# and
username foobar..token
# and
--username=foobar..token
# and
foobar..token@host.name:port
# and some other
# that I found in https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/client/client_shared.c
```

but in all cases I have just

```
Error: Unknown option '--username.. and so on'.
```

and I'm not very good at C-lang.. Can someone please tell me how to cook it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A-ha, seems I found it (in the last possible combination I didn't test):

```
# ~/.config/mosquitto_pub
--username <username-or-token>
-h <broker.addre.ss>
# and so on
```

So, proper format is **with leadig dashes** and **without equal sign**

Now it allows to exec `mosquitto_pub` with short parameter list:

```
mosquitto_pub -t mydata/update -m 4
```